# Python slice without dimension

Tags: python, arrays

Why slicing one row or column produces "dimensionless array"? For example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.zeros((10,10))
print arr.shape
# (10, 10)
```

But when I want only one column or row, I get

```
print arr[:,0].shape
# (10,)
print arr[0,:].shape
# (10,)
```

instead of

```
print arr[:,0].shape
# (10, 1)
print arr[0,:].shape
# (1, 10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For you example you getting `np.arrays` from 0 column and from 0 row which are `numpy.array` with 1 dimension. You could do a little trick with slicing like that:

```
In [103]: arr[:1,:].shape
Out[103]: (1, 10)

In [104]: arr[:,:1].shape
Out[104]: (10, 1)
```

**EDIT**

From [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> An integer, `i`, returns the same values as `i:i+1` **except** the dimensionality of the returned object is reduced by 1. In particular, a selection tuple with the p-th element an integer (and all other entries `:`) returns the corresponding sub-array with dimension N - 1. If N = 1 then the returned object is an array scalar. These objects are explained in Scalars.

Comment: So if I need 3rd column (0, 1, **2**, ...), I guess `arr[:,2:3]` would do it without the need of `reshape(10,1)` afterwards. Thanks, it is a nice trick.

Comment: But why is it _so_ complicated? Is there any reason for creating dimensionless slices? Could you edit your answer so it would explain that too?